# Problem:String array set on TextView

Tags: android, arrays

I want to change text from the textview when I was click the next button. I have try this code but could not get right direction. would you please fix it.

```
public class StringTestActivity extends ListActivity {
TextView t;
int count=0;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    t=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);

    Resources res = this.getResources();
    final String[] capital = res.getStringArray(R.array.Cap);

       //ArrayAdapter<String> n=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,capital);
       //setListAdapter(n);
    Button next=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnNext);
    next.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(count<capital.length-1)
            t.setText(capital[count]);
            count++;
        }

    });
```

}
 }

**Edit:** I have faced this error message.
[image]

**again edited:** main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent">

   <TextView android:id="@+id/list" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:hint="text" />

   <Button android:text="Next" android:id="@+id/btnNext"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">   </Button>        

</LinearLayout>
```

res/string/array.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <resources>
  <string-array name="Cap">
    <item>A</item>
    <item>B</item>
    <item>C</item>
    <item>D</item>
  </string-array>
 </resources>
```

Comment: what u r getting wrong ? will u elaborate what problem u r getting?

Comment: when I run this project, above message was display(sorry.....). any thing wrong my code.

Comment: Provide us the error messages u r getting in your logcat. Not his image.

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{a.b/a.b.StringTestActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3264/discussion-between-kshetri-horrorgoogle-and-android-power)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not using ListView then implement **Activity** not **ListActivity**. So make this change

**public class StringTestActivity extends Activity {**

Also **import android.app.Activity**

Comment: I got error on line>>>  t=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.list); on **list**.

Comment: Would you please give some idea behind this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7332112/how-to-make-horizontal-scrolling-view-in-android

Answer (score 2):

```
Button btn1;
 String countires[];
 int i=0;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.prob2);

    btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.prob2_btn1);

    countires = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.country);

    for (String string : countires)
    {
        Log.i("--: VALUE :--","string = "+string);
    }

    btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String  country  = countires[i];
            btn1.setText(country);
            i++;
            if(i==countires.length)
                i=0;
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            t.setText(capital[count]);
            count++;
            count=count%capital.length;
        }
```

Comment: use  t=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.list);

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks ok, what do you mean by "could not get right direction"? Does it crash with an exception, does the code never change?

By the way, considering your button is called next, you may want to rewrite it like this:

```
    Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        count++;
        if( count < capital.length ) // no - 1
        {
            t.setText(capital[count]);
        } else {
            /* perhaps v.setEnabled(false); ? */
        }
    }
```

Comment: I try already this capital.length that not ok . tell me something more.

Comment: Are you sure the Force Close comes from that code? How about posting the logs, instead of just a picture?

Comment: 09-08 12:25:21.420: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13400): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{a.b/a.b.StringTestActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'

Comment: Well, that has nothing to do with the code you posted. The exception you are getting is because "Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'". Check your layout (R.layout.main) and ensure there is a ListView item named @android:id/list.